# SAS SQL create table depending on macro variable result

Tags: sql, variables, if-statement, sas, sas-macro

I am struggling with creating a new table in proc sql SAS depending on macro variable result.

1) I want to check if necessary table exists.

2) If it exists then I want to create a new table with given parameters.

3) If it doesn't exist I want to create a new table with different parameters.

I think I know how to check if table exists (0 or 1 in log results):

```
        %let tex1 = %sysfunc(exist(Base.pk_&monthP1));   
        %put tex1 = &tex1.;
```

But I do not know how to implement this result into proc sql statement.

I need sth like this:

```
        proc sql;
        create table test as
        select case when &text1 = 0 then select ...
        else 
        select ...
        end ;
        quit;
```

Thank you in advance for suggested solutions.

Comment: This question is probably at the beginner tutorial level. You may have to learn the basics elsewhere and ask here if you have a problem implementing it and mention what you have tried. SO requires these, for this to be a good question for others to answer.

Comment: Hi! I tried to do this with case logic but it didn't work. Other examples that I found inculded quite complicated macro statements. I was looking for the answer, I didn't find it. That is why I am asking for help.

Comment: Does the #2 table have different columns than the #3 table ?

Comment: No. Both tables have the same columns (the same structure). The only difference is that one table has data from for example July and the other table has data from August. Based on the result from &text1 I want to get the data from table1 or table 2.

Comment: @Ela, why not simply use one large dataset with a column indicator fo *July*, *August*, etc.? Easier to use a `WHERE` condition on column than query different datasets.

Comment: First I have to check if there is a table with data from last month. If it is available then I have to use it. If not, I have to use data from the month before that. I repeat this procedure every month.

Answer (score 0):

So if both tables have the same structure then the only part of the SQL code that needs to change is the FROM clause.  It is probably easier to conditionally set a macro variable to the name to use and replace the name of the dataset with a reference to the macro variable.

```
select var1,varb, ....
  from &dsname.
```

Now the problem becomes one of just setting the macro variable.  You could do that with macro logic.  But you could also just do that with data step logic.

```
data _null_ ;
  if exist("Base.pk_&monthP1") then call symputx('dsname','table1');
  else call symputx('dsname','table2');
run;
proc sql;
   ... from &dsname. ...
```

Comment: Tom, with this data step can I: check if table exists, if yes then create table1 as select from source1, if no then create table2 as select from source2? Call symputx will execute one of the two proc sql (for table1 or table2)?